# GWT TextBox widget

Tags: gwt, textbox

I have a well populated Object which has properties like color,size,weight etc.
I need to get these object properties and place them in a TextBox.

So i want to do something like

```
   `textBox.getLine1.setText(Object.getColor());
    textBox.getLine2.setText(Object.getWeight());`
```

That is i need a textBox in which i can edit individual lines.

I am planning to have a widget which has a FlexTable inside the TextBox but i am not sure how to work on it.

Can someone please help me on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something similar: I needed to let user select one or several text rows and let each row be clickable to perform an action.

So I used a VerticalPanel with Labels.

```
VerticalPanel labelPanel = new VerticalPanel();
```

For a given index Label:

```
Label selectedLabel = (Label) labelPanel.getWidget(index);
DOM.setElementAttribute(selectedLabel.getElement(), "id", "label-selected");
```

CSS code as you wish!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're looking for the `RichTextArea` widget

You can check the documentation here: [RichTextArea](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.html)

And an old, but nice tutorial here: [Tutorial](http://examples.roughian.com/Widgets__RichTextArea.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use a TextArea, which is a standard `<input type="text">` element, you would have to find line breaks and create a Selection, and then replace it with whatever you want. You could also read the entire text, change it, and then update the entire TextArea value again.

I would recommend splitting your widget into multiple single line TextBoxes.